# Set the exact number of elements required for an Input field with type number

Tags: html, input, maxlength

I have a field input with type number in my form I would like to allow exact 13 characters to that field no less no more as per the requirement. I wanted to know is there any by default option in HTML using which I can accomplish this? I tried pattern and maxlength but for some reason they are ineffective with the type number. If it is not possible from HTML side then I would like to achieve the same using the angularjs. Any inputs would be really useful.

```
<input type="number" id="userCode" ng-model="formdata.userCode" title="13 Digit code"></input>&nbsp;
```

As per the below answer I added the `min` and `max` as 13. After adding it when I enter even 13 digits then also I get the error. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

```
<input type="number" min="13" max="13" id="userCode" ng-model="formdata.userCode" placeholder="Enter 13 Digit Code" title="Please Enter the 13 digit code" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" ng-required="true">&nbsp;
```

[image]

Comment: use `min` & `max` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking they can also check this answer:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{13,13}" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''); title="13 characters length required" ">
```

With this input field although its text we can make sure that it accepts only the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" required pattern="[0-9]{13}" maxlength=13 id="userCode" ng-model="formdata.userCode" title="13 Digit code">&nbsp;
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp) for some other attributes of input to play around with.

Comment: I have added this command but for some reason even if I enter 13 digits it is throwing error. I have modified my question and added the screenshot. Can you please check and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I am trying with the input type of `number` when I add the `pattern=".{13,13}"` I am not seeing any difference. Can you please let me know if it's applicable only for the `text` type? How can I implement it for the `number` field?

Comment: You must have to change the `type` attribute to `text` otherwise it will not going to work for you! all these attributes like `maxlength`, `minlength`  or even `pattern` not works on `numbers`. I also know that you are using `type="number"` here but right now if you look at my updated answer if user puts any text in the field it will throw error while pressing the `submit` button. Only numbers are going to be accepted but the key here is you must change the type to `text`.

Comment: oh ok sure I used the following regex so now it accepts only numbers.
`oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');"`